# Let $f\colon \Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ be a function such that $f(x)>x^2$ for every $x \in\Bbb R$. Prove that $f'$ is not bounded.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f\colon \Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ be a differentiable function such that $f(x)>x^2$ for every $x \in\Bbb R$. Prove that $f'$ is not bounded.

I'm struggling on a starting point here. An example of $f(x)$ could be $f(x)=x^2+1$ so $f'(x)=2x$. So can I prove this is not bounded and then relate it to the original function?

Comment: Giving an example where the result holds will not prove it. Instead you might start by assuming that $f'$ is bounded and deduce that $f(x)\gt x^2$ is impossible for $x$ large enough.

Comment: Mean value theorem.

Answer (score 3):

Assume that $f'$ is bounded above by $M>0$ then
$$x^2\le f(x)=\int_0^x f'(t)dt+f(0)\leq Mx+f(0)\quad\forall x\ge0$$
so

$$x\le M+\frac{f(0)}{x}\quad \forall x>0$$
and by passing to the limit $x\to\infty$ we find the contradiction.

Comment: The hypothesis is $f$ is differentiable.  That is not quite enough to (Riemann or Lebesgue) integrate $f'$ and recover $f$.  This is where the hint by dfeuer comes in.

Comment: For my sleepy bro :+)

Comment: Nice and concise! +1